# Using Hard coded database in react native

Tags: javascript, json, database, react-native, expo

I am currently working on a project where I can view menus.
I was able select a menu from a horizontal flatlist, which navigates to an add-on screen with image and title of the menu from a hard coded database, but I wasn't sure if I could also bring in the childrens of the database.
Database is built like this. I know I will be using transferring data later one, but I have to hardcode it for now

for example, how could I access the texts to all all sizes of the drink in each menu?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypIfG.png)

Comment: It looks like its a json file, so you just import that file (be sure to add the .json) and treat it like a normal object

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I tried treating it like a normal object. It might be me doing it incorrectly but if I were to use the value of sizetext small, wouldn't I access it as item.addon.size.small.sizetext?

Comment: So the objective is to click a menu from a selection page, then render image and menu text in the next page. But as you see from the database I also have details about the drink such as addons and sizes. I know I have only passed in image and text as param. I am confused on how I can export the whole database of that selected item to the next page and access a specific value of the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be easier to tell if the json was text and not an image

Comment: but it looks like its an array so try starting with item[0]